# Slack Modal message using web-hook not opening in the slack channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm using a web-hook to post a modal interactive message in the Slack channel but the message is not displayed in the Slack channel.

There is some information regarding the trigger id from the Slack documentation but it is very confusing.

Below is my JSON payload, where I'm using the prebuild template from Slack and using a web-hook to send the message to the Slack channel.

```html
var message={};
var attachments = [];
var attachment = {
    "type": "modal",
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Your accommodation",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please choose an option where you'd like to stay from Oct 21 - Oct 23 (2 nights).",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Airstream Suite*\n*Share with another person*. Private walk-in bathroom. TV. Heating. Kitchen with microwave, basic cooking utensils, wine glasses and silverware."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/Streamline-Beach.png",
                "alt_text": "Airstream Suite"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "1x Queen Bed"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "|"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "$220 / night"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Choose",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "View Details",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Redwood Suite*\n*Share with 2 other person*. Studio home. Modern bathroom. TV. Heating. Full kitchen. Patio with lounge chairs and campfire style fire pit and grill."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/redwoodcabin.png",
                "alt_text": "Redwood Suite"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "1x King Bed"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "|"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "$350 / night"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "✓ Your Choice",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "style": "primary",
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "View Details",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Luxury Tent*\n*One person only*. Shared modern bathrooms and showers in lounge building. Temperature control with heated blankets. Lights and electrical outlets."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/tent.png",
                "alt_text": "Redwood Suite"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "1x Queen Bed"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "|"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "$260 / night"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Choose",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "View Details",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        }
    ]
};
attachments.push(attachment);
message.attachments = attachments;
print(JSON.stringify(message));
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a trigger_id to open a modal. Basically, Slack will only let you display a modal if the user says "show me the modal!" This prevents a developer from sending annoying, unwanted modals to unsuspecting users. You can get the trigger_id when a user interacts with one of the app "[entry points](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/entry-points)":

1. Short cuts
2. Slash commands
3. An interactive element in the app UI (like a button)

When the user interacts with one of those entry points, they're telling you they want to see the modal, so Slack will send you an [interaction payload](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#payloads) with the trigger_id. For a global shortcut, that payload may look like [this](https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/shortcuts#reference-shortcuts-interaction-payloads__examples):

```
{
  "type": "shortcut",
  "token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "action_ts": "1581106241.371594",
  "team": {
    "id": "TXXXXXXXX",
    "domain": "shortcuts-test"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "UXXXXXXXXX",
    "username": "aman",
    "team_id": "TXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "callback_id": "shortcut_create_event",
  "trigger_id": "944799105734.773906753841.38b5894552bdd4a780554ee59d1f3638"
}
```

So basically, you need to create one of those first and setup your app to receive a POST request from Slack.

Once you know the user *wants* the modal to appear, you can tell Slack to open the modal. Create a [view payload](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/views) (the attachment in your code) and include the trigger_id that you received. Send this payload to [views.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open) endpoint. Note that you're *not* sending a message payload as you have in your code and remember that the trigger_id expires within 3 seconds.

```
var payload = {
  trigger_id: "944799105734.773906753841.38b5894552bdd4a780554ee59d1f3638",
  view: {
    "type": "modal",
    "submit": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Submit",
      "emoji": true
    },
    "close": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Cancel",
      "emoji": true
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Your accommodation",
      "emoji": true
    },
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Please choose an option where you'd like to stay from Oct 21 - Oct 23 (2 nights).",
          "emoji": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Here's the entire flow describing who does what and in what order:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜┌─────────────┐◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜┌─────────────┐◜│
│◜┌─────────┐◜◜│  Selects a  │◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│  Sees the   │◜│
│◜│  USER   │◜◜│  shortcut   │─┐◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜┌─▶│    modal    │◜│
│◜└─────────┘◜◜│             │◜│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│◜◜│             │◜│
│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜└─────────────┘◜│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│◜◜└─────────────┘◜│
├──────────────────────────────▼──────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┤
│                       ┌─────────────┐                        ┌─────────────┐           │
│ ┌──────────┐          │  Generates  │                        │  Opens the  │           │
│ │  SLACK   │          │ interaction │                        │    modal    │           │
│ └──────────┘          │   payload   │                        │             │           │
│                       └─────────────┘                        └─────────────┘           │
├──────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────▲──────────────────┤
│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│◜◜◜┌─────────────┐◜◜◜┌─────────────┐◜◜│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│
│◜┌──────────┐◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│◜◜◜│  Extracts   │◜◜◜│ Sends modal │◜◜│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│
│◜│ YOUR APP │◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜└──▶│ trigger_id  │──▶│  data with  │──┘◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│
│◜└──────────┘◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│             │◜◜◜│ trigger_id  │◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│
│◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜└─────────────┘◜◜◜└─────────────┘◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜◜│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: how did you generate that workflow diagram?

Comment: @DomVinyard https://monodraw.helftone.com